# Creating Dynamic Tables in Word by C#.NET

Tags: c#, dynamic, ms-word

I have a C# application where i want to implement a logic for a programm which will open the word document and go to a certain place in the page and create a Table and put values in that. Can any one tell me how to implement this. I am using Visual studio 2005

Comment: (re your comment to me) I hate to tell you this, but Word is not a managed application. So to use the Word app itself, you are going to have to use the COM api... the alternative is to use a 3rd-party tool to write word files directly (easier with .docx than .doc).

Answer (score 7):

Here is code to copy datagridview to a word table:

Reference is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

```
using word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;    
public static void ExportToWord(DataGridView dgv)
                {
                    SendMessage("Opening Word");

                    word.ApplicationClass word = null;



      word.Document doc = null;
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */ 
            try
            {
                word = new word.ApplicationClass();
                word.Visible = true;
                doc = word.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
            if (word != null && doc != null)
            {
                word.Table newTable;
                word.Range wrdRng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
                newTable = doc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, 1, dgv.Columns.Count-1, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                newTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
                newTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
                newTable.AllowAutoFit = true;

                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgv.Rows[0].Cells)
                {
                    newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, cell.ColumnIndex).Range.Text = dgv.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex].Name;

                }
                newTable.Rows.Add();

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, cell.ColumnIndex).Range.Text = cell.Value.ToString();                      
                    }
                    newTable.Rows.Add();
                }                                              
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Look up "Word Automation".

For example, [KB316384](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384), which covers:

The sample code in this article demonstrates how to do the following:

- Insert paragraphs with text and formatting.
- Browse and modify various ranges within a document.
- Insert tables, format tables, and populate the tables with data.
- Add a chart.

Comment: Thanks.But i am looking for a solution which use .NET Reference instead of COM reference.Searched a lot.But couldnt findout .Can any one ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Word Automation, e.g. you don't have Word installed on the computer running your program, you should have a look at [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.words-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx).

The only problem is that it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

Word will quite happily open a file in HTML with the extension .Doc. You can have all the formatting you want by using an internal style sheet. A very similar question came up here:

[Export to Word Document in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282531/export-to-word-document-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can try my method to export data to Word (*.docx) , it's easy to use and works 100% with any DataGridView , just add **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** reference and copy the following code :

```
    using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

   public void Export_Data_To_Word(DataGridView DGV, string filename)
   {
    if (DGV.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        int RowCount = DGV.Rows.Count;
        int ColumnCount = DGV.Columns.Count;
        Object[,] DataArray = new object[RowCount + 1, ColumnCount + 1];

        //add rows
        int r = 0;
        for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
        {
            for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
            {
                DataArray[r, c] = DGV.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
            } //end row loop
        } //end column loop

        Word.Document oDoc = new Word.Document();
        oDoc.Application.Visible = true;

        //page orintation
        oDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;


        dynamic oRange = oDoc.Content.Application.Selection.Range;
        string oTemp = "";
        for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
                oTemp = oTemp + DataArray[r, c] + "\t";

            }
        }

        //table format
        oRange.Text = oTemp;

        object Separator = Word.WdTableFieldSeparator.wdSeparateByTabs;
        object ApplyBorders = true;
        object AutoFit = true;
        object AutoFitBehavior = Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent;

        oRange.ConvertToTable(ref Separator, ref RowCount, ref ColumnCount,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ref ApplyBorders,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                              Type.Missing, ref AutoFit, ref AutoFitBehavior, Type.Missing);

        oRange.Select();

        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Select();
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = 0;
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Alignment = 0;
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
        oDoc.Application.Selection.InsertRowsAbove(1);
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();

        //header row style
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Bold = 1;
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Size = 14;

        //add header row manually
        for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
        {
            oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Text = DGV.Columns[c].HeaderText;
        }

        //table style 
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].set_Style("Grid Table 4 - Accent 5");
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
        oDoc.Application.Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;

        //header text
        foreach (Word.Section section in oDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections)
        {
            Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
            headerRange.Text = "your header text";
            headerRange.Font.Size = 16;
            headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        }

      //save the file
        oDoc.SaveAs2(filename);

         //NASSIM LOUCHANI
    }  
   }




  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    sfd.Filter = "Word Documents (*.docx)|*.docx";

    sfd.FileName = "export.docx";

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        Export_Data_To_Word(dataGridView1, sfd.FileName); 
    }
   }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code for insert table in to specific bookmark retreiving model in database, i hope helps community, i use mvc C#, microsoft office interop word for create a word file and add dynamic table from helper class

```
public void tableFromDatabase(Document doc, Application word, string risk, string bookmarkName, TableTemplate table) {
        Table newTable;//Create a new table
        Range wrdRng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(bookmarkName).Range;//Get a bookmark Range
        doc.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Select();
        newTable = word.Selection.Tables.Add(wrdRng,1,1);//Add new table to selected bookmark by default set 1 row, 1 column (need set interval 1-63)
        newTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
        newTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
        int a=0, b=0;//Set integer values for iterate in model arrays
        //Iterate model rows
        for (int i = 1; i <= table.Rows.Count; i++)//Set in 1 the value because in word tables the begin is (1,1)
        {
            //Only add rows if is after first row
            if (i > 1)
            {
                newTable.Rows.Add();
            }
            //Iterate model columns from rows
            for (int j = 1; j <= table.Rows[a].Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                //Only Add rows if is after first
                if (j == 1 && i == 1)
                {
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Font.Name = table.Rows[a].Columns[b].cellFontName;
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Font.Size = table.Rows[a].Columns[b].cellFontSize;
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Width = float.Parse(table.Rows[a].Columns[b].cellWidth);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add Cells to rows only if columns of the model is largen than table, this is for not exceed the interval
                    if (newTable.Rows[i].Cells.Count < table.Rows[a].Columns.Count)
                    {
                        newTable.Rows[i].Cells.Add();
                    }
                    //Set the values to new table
                    //The width must be float type
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Font.Name = table.Rows[a].Columns[b].cellFontName;
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Font.Size = table.Rows[a].Columns[b].cellFontSize;
                    newTable.Cell(i, j).Width = float.Parse(table.Rows[a].Columns[b].cellWidth);
                }
                b++;
                //Set 0 to reset cycle
                if (b == table.Rows[a].Columns.Count)
                {
                    b = 0;
                }
            }
            a++;
            //Set 0 to reset cycle
            if (a == table.Rows.Count)
            {
                a = 0;
            }
        }
        newTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
        newTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
        newTable.AllowAutoFit = true;
        //Set gray color to borders
        newTable.Borders.InsideColor = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor)12964311;
        newTable.Borders.OutsideColor = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor)12964311;

    }
```