# Converting page contents into MS word in C# ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I have stored page contents (tables, plain text, images and paragraphs) into a variable. Now i want to convert this variable contents into MS word. How i can do this. Is there any possibility available in VS2010? OR is there any free library available for this conversion?

Comment: This may be a good start for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282531/export-to-word-document-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have everything stored somewhere.. you can do something like [Building a Word Document Using SQL Server Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192487%28office.11%29.aspx)

Moreover, there is a good example about [Microsoft Word Documents from ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3959/Microsoft-Word-Documents-from-ASP-NET)

Comment: But i need solution without having installed MS word on computer. Want to convert HTML contents into MS word .doc format without having installed MS word on system